# asp.net core dependency passing dependencies along

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to inject a dependency into a class used internally in a controller,

I have

```
//Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    services.AddMvc();//IDocumentService is a WCF service from our legacy stack
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IDocumentService),typeof(DocumentServiceClient));
}
//Controller.cs
[Route("api/eci/test/[action]")]
public class Controller{
    private IDocumentService injectedDocService;
    public Controller(IDocumentService client){
        injectedDocService=client;
    }
    [HttpPost({"id"})]
    public void ingestedDocs(string id){
        new Logic(injectedDocService).ingest(id);
    }
}
//Logic.cs
public class Logic{
    private IDocumentService injectedDocServiceActualTarget;
    public Logic(IDocumentService injected2){
        injectedDocServiceActualTarget=injected2;
    }
    public void injest(string id){
        injectedDocServiceActualTarget.doWork(id);
    }
}
```

It seems a little redundant to have it injected to the target class's parent. Is this the right way of doing things?

Comment: You are breaking the DI model by instantiating `Logic` in the controller. Let the container do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the `Logic`, then inject it to the controller. `DocumentService` will be injected to the `Logic` then.

The idea behind dependency injection is to implement the IoC (inversion of control) principle. In your example, it is only partial, since you explicitly instantiate `Logic` in your controller. If you want to do the dependency inversion properly - all your dependencies need to be passed as constructor parameters.

Comment: Injecting classes is not a great idea (if you're into unit testing). I would instead create interface ILogic, have logic implement ILogic and inject ILogic into controller instead.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar in the actual code, Logic is one of a few business logic classes that has specific methods that aren't shared by other logic classes, is it recommended that I make a throwaway interface that duplicates all of the method signatures for each specific class?

Comment: @Austin_Anderson - depends; do you want to unit test your controller ? If so you might need to mock Logic class; mocking classes is non-trivial problem (they has to have every single mockable method virtual) also you need to call the constructor. Mocking interfaces is super easy. If you do not unit test, do what you want :)

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar the point of the logic classes in this architecture is that none of the testable logic goes in the controllers directly, and instead we have a business logic layer with all that code, and a control layer that simply calls the business logic layer. Maybe that's an unnecessary abstraction now that we have dependency injection, but that's what the team decided on. tl;dr, we probably wont test the controllers, just the logic classes

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar it is never a good idea to judge without knowing the context. Although I generally agree with you, this was out of scope for this question. Sometimes, you have a stateless singleton (hence the name `Logic`, which implies just that), which has no point to mock/fake, you can perfectly inject it.

Answer (score 1):

You should abstract the `Logic` behind an interface, only exposing the members that are to be used by dependents.

```
public interface ILogic {
    void injest(string id);
}
```

Have the Logic class derive from the abstraction.

```
//Logic.cs
public class Logic : ILogic {
    private readonly IDocumentService injectedDocServiceActualTarget;

    public Logic(IDocumentService injected2) {
        this.injectedDocServiceActualTarget=injected2;
    }

    public void injest(string id) {
        injectedDocServiceActualTarget.doWork(id);
    }
}
```

The Controller should now only explicitly depend on the `ILogic` interface

```
//Controller.cs
[Route("api/eci/test/[action]")]
public class Controller {
    private readonly ILogic service;

    public Controller(ILogic service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [HttpPost({"id"})]
    public void ingestedDocs(string id) {
        service.ingest(id);
    }
}
```

With that the last thing to do is to register all dependencies with the service collection.

```
//Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<IDocumentService, DocumentServiceClient>();
    services.AddScoped<ILogic, Logic>();
}
```

So now when the controller is called all dependencies will be resolved and injected into their respective dependents.